# AWS CloudFormation provisioning... UserData vs. Ansible or the likes?

Tags: amazon-web-services, ansible, provisioning, aws-cloudformation, terraform

What is the difference between provisioning using AWS CloudFormation UserData vs. Ansible?

I know that in relation to Puppet for example, it enforces provisioning rules even when a change is done (changes it back to reflect the manifest).

But are there more differences which are worth taking into consideration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To clarify, "UserData" is part of an EC2 instance, not part of CloudFormation itself. EC2 instances can be launched with [User Data](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-instance-metadata.html#instancedata-add-user-data), which can be used by the AMI to perform dynamic operations on startup. If CloudFormation is used to launch an EC2 instance, it can provide User Data to the EC2 instance by setting the [`UserData`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-ec2-instance.html#cfn-ec2-instance-userdata) property on the [`AWS::EC2::Instance`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-ec2-instance.html) Resource.

Typically, user data is processed by [`Cloud-Init`](https://cloudinit.readthedocs.io), and is typically formatted as a simple [User-Data Script](https://cloudinit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/format.html#user-data-script) which is just a shell script that gets invoked on the instance when it is first launched.

That said, 'Shell script vs. Ansible' is an apples-to-oranges comparison. Whether or not Ansible is the appropriate software for your use-case depends on whether you need to use the extra layers of abstraction built into Ansible versus a standard shell script to provision what's needed on your instance. Read the [Ansible Documentation](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/) and decide for yourself.

It is worth mentioning that aside from the normal 'push' method of running Ansible to provision your instance via SSH, you can also run Ansible in an inverted, '[Ansible-pull](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_intro.html#ansible-pull)' mode, using a User-Data Script to perform the initial 'bootstrap' installation on the EC2 instance.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is: Use CloudFormation or [Terraform](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/)

Ansible is a configuration managment tool for many diffrent purposes. The most significant diffrence to many of the other tools is, that is is working in a push mode, so there are no agents on the remote server polling for changes. 
It is great when it's about installing packages, creating files and so on.

CloudFormation is desinged to create AWS enviroments. This is good if you onyl use Amazon and nothing else.

Ansible can do the job, but i would recommend to use a tool like CloudFormation or Terraform. The Ansible modules for this are ok, but tools like Terraform have a fokus on creating enviroments and they are much smarter when doing the job.

Comment: Thanks, I'll look into it tomorrow.

Comment: This is a decent answer, except that Ansible is only configuration-management secondarily. and the focus here is on infrastructure provisioning.